# Null Pointer exception when loading XML to Hive

Tags: sql, xml, hive

I'm currently facing some issues when loading an xml file into Hive using hive-serde. I followed the tips here but i'm still receiving a null pointer exception when trying to read the data that had been loading into hive via an xml file. The SQL below runs correctly it is only when trying to read from the table that the issue occurs

Here is the xml with some dummy values

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?><History-Group-Comm-CommB-DT-RBB-Work 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <item id="HISTORY_6_GMT">
    <pxAddedByID>HUBINT</pxAddedByID>
    <pxAddedBySystem>CD</pxAddedBySystem>
    <pxHistoryForReference>GR</pxHistoryForReference>
    <pxInsName>GMT</pxInsName>
    <pxObjClass>Work</pxObjClass>
    <pxTimeCreated>2017-02-13T13:08:28.776Z</pxTimeCreated>
    <pyFlowKey>RULE-OBJ</pyFlowKey>
    <pyFlowName>pyStartCase</pyFlowName>
    <pyFlowType>pyStartCase</pyFlowType>
    <pyMessageKey>ItemCreated</pyMessageKey>
    <pyPerformer>HUB</pyPerformer>
    <pzInsKey>776 GMT</pzInsKey>
    </item>
```

and the sql loading the xml is as follows

```
    add jar hdfs://DEVHDPVM01HA:8020/HADOOP/DASD_ACQ/common/lib/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;


     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.test_tbl_stg;
     CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test.test_tbl_stg  (
     ADDED_BY_ID STRING COMMENT 'pxAddedByID',
     ADDED_BY_SYSTEM STRING COMMENT 'pxAddedBySystem',
     HISTORY_FOR_REFERENCE STRING COMMENT '',
     INSERT_NAME STRING COMMENT '',
     OBJECT_CLASS STRING COMMENT '',
     TIME_CREATED STRING COMMENT '',
     FLOW_KEY STRING COMMENT '',
     FLOW_NAME STRING COMMENT '',
     FLOW_TYPE FLOAT COMMENT '',
     MESSAGE STRING COMMENT '',
     PERFORMER STRING COMMENT '',
     INSERT_KEY STRING COMMENT '' ) COMMENT 'Optional Table Comment'
     ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
     WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     "column.xpath.ADDED_BY_ID"="/item/pxAddedByID/text()", 
     "column.xpath.ADDED_BY_SYSTEM"="/item/pxAddedBySystem/text()",
   "column.xpath.HISTORY_FOR_REFERENCE"="/item/pxHistoryForReference/text()",
    "column.xpath.INSERT_NAME"="/item/pxInsName/text()",
    "column.xpath.OBJECT_CLASS"="/item/pxObjClass/text()",
    "column.xpath.TIME_CREATED"="/item/pxTimeCreated/text()",
    "column.xpath.FLOW_KEY"="/item/pyFlowKey/text()",
    "column.xpath.FLOW_NAME"="/item/pyFlowName/text()",
    "column.xpath.FLOW_TYPE"="/item/pyFlowType/text()",
    "column.xpath.MESSAGE"="/item/pyMessageKey/text()",
    "column.xpath.PERFORMER"="/item/pyPerformer/text()",
    "column.xpath.INSERT_KEY"="/item/pzInsKey/text()")
    STORED AS
    INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION '${stagingFolderPath}'
    TBLPROPERTIES ("xmlinput.start"="<item id=","xmlinput.end"="</item>");
```

Any suggestions as to why this null pointer exception is occurring are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert this field data type
     FLOW_TYPE FLOAT COMMENT ''
        to 
     FLOW_TYPE STRING COMMENT '',

because of conversion i think you are facing this problem

Comment: You were absolutely right, many thanks. Is there a list somewhere which details field types that are accepted when processing XML files in Hive